# Cannot run React Native app after ejecting Expo

Tags: android, ios, node.js, react-native, npm

I ran `npm run eject` and after that cannot run my project. I get this error:

```
In file included from /Users/patrickbassut/Programming/beebo/.expo-source/ios/ios/Exponent/Versioned/Modules/Internal/EXDevSettings.m:3:
/Users/patrickbassut/Programming/beebo/.expo-source/ios/ios/Exponent/Versioned/Modules/Internal/EXDevSettings.h:3:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTDevSettings.h' file not found
#import <React/RCTDevSettings.h>
        ^
1 error generated.


** BUILD FAILED **



The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/patrickbassut/Programming/beebo/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExpoKit.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EXDevSettings.o /Users/patrickbassut/Programming/beebo/.expo-source/ios/ios/Exponent/Versioned/Modules/Internal/EXDevSettings.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/beebo.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/beebo.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

- react-native: **0.49.5**
- npm: **4.6.1**
- watchman: **4.7.0**
- node: **8.1.3**

If someone had a similar issue and managed to resolve it successfully, please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you trying to run your app? What steps did you take to get this error? Have you tried reinstalling node modules, resetting watchman and clearing npm cache?

Comment: yes, i reinstalled npm modules, cleared cache, resetted watchman, installed pods...

Comment: Are you running the app with `react-native run-ios` (assuming you’re running iOS)

Comment: yes. I recreated my project with react-native init and c/p the code. now it's working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happened to me too. I had a lot of problems after ejecting Expo. I decided to create my project again using:

> react-native init yourAppName

instead of

> create-react-native-app yourAppName

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem after ejecting but mine was 'Chalk was missing'. So I solved it by running the following commands:

```
  npm install chalk
  npm install easy-async
  npm install indent-string
```

I got the solution from this [thread](https://github.com/addyosmani/a11y/issues/13)